Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions,Version=4.2.0.0
I installed the Azure.Identity(Latest) and Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus(latest) because I want to connect with Service bus using ManagedIdentity.
private readonly ServiceBusSender _sender;
    private const string QUEUENAME = "test";
    public QueueService()
    {
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusNameSpace"], new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManagedIdentityClientId"], null));
        _sender = client.CreateSender(QUEUENAME);
    }

After drafting code, I'm facing issue related to loading the assembly.
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
I tried to fix it with some steps
. Downloaded the latest version of System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions and point to the latest version.

But not able to resolve this, also unittests are failing due to dependency.

If you have a web.config or app.config, check if you have any binding redirection incorrect, or try adding a binding redirection to the specific version you want to use. In the bin folder you can check if the dll is there, and which version gets copied. You might have other dependencies which uses an older (or newer) version.

you can try nuget clear cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders
Then run update-Package -reinstall command
